# VS2012 TFS shows pending change, but I cannot find it

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Within Visual Studio 2012, on the "Team Explorer - Pending Changes" window I have a supposedly changed file.  When viewing the change with "Compare with Workspace Version", no change is located on the Diff.  No change is found when using "Compare with Latest Version" either.

I want to undo whatever change it thinks it is seeing.  I do not want to try checking in a mystery change.

I have tried...

- right-clicking on the file and selecting "Undo".  No luck.
- "Get Latest Version (Recursive)" and repeating all steps above.  No luck.
- Rebooting Windows. No luck.

Comment: What happens when you undo?

Comment: It behaves the same way as if it successfully performed the "Undo".   However, the file remains listed as a pending change.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clear your TFS cache?

1. Shut down all instances of Visual Studio/Blend/etc...
2. Open a command shell as Administrator
3. rmdir /s /q "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache"

   - Note TFS2010 is ..\3.0\Cache, TFS2013 is ..\5.0\Cache
4. Re-open Visual Studio and see if that does the trick

Comment: Thanks for the thought.  I'll be sure to try this when the problem shows up again.  Using "Undo" on the file has cleared it out this morning (after letting the PC sit powered on over the weekend).